# In actionscript, is there a clever way to wire specific variables together in such that when one changes, it sends it's change down the wire?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Blue sky, you would have:

```
StaticUtil.wire( fromProperty:*, toProperty:*, usingExpression:Function );
```

and use it like:

```
sprite1.x = 100;
sprite2.width = 200;
StaticUtil.wire( sprite1.x, sprite2.width, function(fromX:Number,toWidth:Number):void{ toWidth = fromX * 2; });

sprite.x = 150;
trace(sprite2.width); //300;
```

I've discovered that dynamically overriding getters/setters is most likely impossible in actionscript... which has led me to this preliminary solution:

```
public class WireableSprite extends Sprite implements IWire
{
    private var _wire:IWire;

    public function WireableSprite()
    {
        super();
    }

    public function wireTo( wireable:IWire ):void
    {
        _wire = wireable;
    }

    override public function set rotation(value:Number):void
    {
        super.rotation = value;
        if( _wire ) _wire["rotation"] = value;
    }

    override public function set scaleX(value:Number):void
    {
        super.scaleX = value;
        if( _wire ) _wire["scaleX"] = value;
    }

    override public function set scaleY(value:Number):void
    {
        super.scaleY = value;
        if( _wire ) _wire["scaleY"] = value;
    }

    override public function set x(value:Number):void
    {
        super.x = value;
        if( _wire ) _wire["x"] = value;
    }

    override public function set y(value:Number):void
    {
        super.y = value;
        if( _wire ) _wire["y"] = value;
    }

}
```

and use it like:

```
myWireableSprite.wireTo( myOtherSprite );
```

which isn't very flexible really...

My question is, does anyone know a clever and more flexible way to do this where I don't have so much duplicated code?

Comment: You can always bind properties together, but it is incredibly inefficient and not recommended for anything other than spot uses.

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look at

```
BindingUtils
```

and

```
ChangeWatcher
```

If I understand you correct, this is what you are looking for.